# Remote access to virtualenv

Tags: linux, apache, flask, virtualenv, wsgi

I have apache `httpd` installed on server `10.37.45.89` which is having `wsgi_module` installed in it.I have placed my `wsgi.conf` file under `/etc/apache2/conf.d` location having details as following:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName my.webtool

    WSGIDaemonProcess webtool user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/home/user/flask-dev
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/flask-dev/webtool.wsgi

    <directory /home/user/flask-dev>
        WSGIProcessGroup webtool
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

I have `Flask` installed on another server  `10.37.45.90` in which i have first set up `virtualenv` in following manner

```
(user@ajdfhklfhasjdf01 [~/flask-dev]) sudo pip install virtualenv
(user@ajdfhklfhasjdf01 [~/flask-dev]) sudo virtualenv venv
(user@ajdfhklfhasjdf01 [~/flask-dev]) source venv/bin/activate
(venv)(user@ajdfhklfhasjdf01 [~/flask-dev])
(venv)(user@ajdfhklfhasjdf01 [~/flask-dev]) sudo pip install Flask
```

I have following hierarchy of my code and wsgi file:

```
(venv)(user@ajdfhklfhasjdf01 [~/flask-dev])$ ls
__init__.py*  webtool.wsgi*

(venv)(user@ajdfhklfhasjdf01 [~/flask-dev])$ cat webtool.wsgi
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/flask-dev')
from webtool import app as application

(venv)(user@ajdfhklfhasjdf01 [~/flask-dev])$ cat __init__.py
import socket
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
host_ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello world!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host=host_ip_address,port=30004)
```

I am not sure as to how to perform linkage between these two servers so that Flask can serve request given by httpd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this topic, but I think if you are running your python application on a different server, WSGI might be not possible / the wrong choice.

Instead: set your apache up to act as a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)

Run your flask app on the remote server using a "production-quality" WSGI server instead of flask's built-in werkzeug development WSGI server.
Popular choices are uWSGI, gunicorn, gevent, ...

I found [waitress](https://github.com/Pylons/waitress) to be a good choice for that.
It comes with an command line tool, so you can start your app by issueing:
`waitress-serve --port=8080 myapp:wsgifunc`

Then have your apache proxy to http://:8080.

Comment: Thanks sebastian,i found it really useful and have used `waitress` to setup the same.One concern is that my both ec2 instances can listen each other on specific port so i have setup the waitess on that `host_ip_address:host_port`.So is it really necessary to setup reverse proxy in apache too.